# Combine tags [fish] and [fish-shell]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

There are two substantially identical tags, [fish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fish) and [fish-shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fish-shell).  The first has 45 followers and 123 questions, the second 23 followers and 36 questions.  The tag descriptions make it clear that they are for the same shell.

I don't have enough (as in, any?) points to be able to propose that these should be synonymized, but it is fairly clear that they should be.  On the whole, despite the disparity in the current followers and number of questions, I think that the [fish-shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fish-shell) should be the primary name and [fish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fish) should be the synonym for it.

Comment: Given the low number of questions tagged, it might just be better to retag [fish] to [fish-shell]

Comment: Given that there are now a lot more questions tagged with [tag:fish] then there are [tag:fish-shell], and that I agree with OP that [tag:fish-shell] is the better name, can someone with enough points to do it revisit this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [fish-shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fish-shell) tag has been removed, quite possibly years ago.